# How to save snapshot of systat output?

Tags: freebsd

I often use command `systat -ifstat` to get a snapshot of network activity: how much traffic our file server receives from 3 networks (there is global one, and 2 VLANs). We have different microscopes on different networks, so it's useful to say "we have so much trafic in past month from these 'scopes"

```
 @freenas] ~# systat -ifstat
                /0   /1   /2   /3   /4   /5   /6   /7   /8   /9   /10
 Load Average

  Interface           Traffic               Peak                Total
    epair0a  in      0.000 KB/s          0.000 KB/s          776.518 MB
             out     0.000 KB/s          0.000 KB/s           89.351 GB

    bridge0  in      0.000 KB/s          0.000 KB/s          180.075 GB
             out     0.000 KB/s          0.000 KB/s           73.352 TB

        lo0  in      0.000 KB/s          0.000 KB/s           14.709 GB
             out     0.000 KB/s          0.000 KB/s           14.709 GB

        ix1  in      0.000 KB/s          0.000 KB/s            1.196 TB
             out     0.000 KB/s          0.000 KB/s          987.869 GB

       igb1  in      0.000 KB/s          0.000 KB/s            1.340 GB
             out     0.000 KB/s          0.000 KB/s           35.027 GB

       igb0  in      0.000 KB/s          0.000 KB/s           46.266 TB
             out     0.000 KB/s          0.000 KB/s           73.209 TB
```

However, I would rather have such snapshot emailed to me once in a while for record keeping. How can I do it? Usual redirect of output doesn't work because `systat -ifstat` is a "screen-oriented" utility.

How can I take a snapshot of `systat -ifstat` in a file? More precisely, how can I get a snapshot of amount of traffic that went through interfaces?

```
@freenas] ~# uname -a
FreeBSD freenas.local 9.3-RELEASE-p8 FreeBSD 9.3-RELEASE-p8 #1 r275790+18ab2bc: Wed Jan 21 12:32:31 PST 2015     root@build3.ixsystems.com:/tank/home/jkh/build/93/FN/objs/os-base/amd64/fusion/jkh/93/FN/FreeBSD/src/sys/FREENAS.amd64  amd64
```

Answer (score 2):

[Sysstat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=systat) is as you write meant for interactive usage. If you read through the man page you will notice at the end that there are references to other commands as well:

```
SEE ALSO
     netstat(1), kvm(3), icmp(4), icmp6(4), ip(4), ip6(4), tcp(4), udp(4),
     gstat(8), iostat(8), vmstat(8)
```

The first reference is to [netstat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=netstat) which is:

```
NAME
     netstat - show network status and statistics
```

This is then the tool for gathering statistics in a non-interactive way. You want to know how much traffic goes through the interfaces?

```
netstat -i
```

Which gives the output:

```
Name    Mtu Network       Address              Ipkts Ierrs Idrop    Opkts Oerrs  Coll
em0    1500 <Link#1>      00:00:00:00:00:00  1716175     0     0  1557634     0     0
em0       - fe80::%em0/64 0000::0000:000:00        0     -     -        3     -     -
em0       - 11.11.11.0/   static.11.11.11     245402     -     -  1551992     -     -
lo0   16384 <Link#2>      lo0                    530     0     0      530     0     0
lo0       - localhost     localhost                0     -     -        0     -     -
lo0       - fe80::%lo0/64 fe80::1%lo0              0     -     -        0     -     -
lo0       -               localhost              265     -     -      530     -     -
lo1   16384 <Link#3>      lo1                      0     0     0        0     0     0
lo1       - 172.17.2.0/24 172.17.2.0               0     -     -        0     -     -
lo1       - 172.17.2.1/32 172.17.2.1              21     -     -        0     -     -
lo1       - 172.17.2.2/32 172.17.2.2              50     -     -        0     -     -
lo1       - 172.17.2.3/32 172.17.2.3              22     -     -        0     -     -
lo1       - 172.17.2.4/32 172.17.2.4              36     -     -        0     -     -
lo1       - 172.17.2.5/32 172.17.2.5              32     -     -        0     -     -
lo1       - 172.17.2.6/32 172.17.2.6              27     -     -        0     -     -
lo1       - 172.17.2.7/32 172.17.2.7              26     -     -        0     -     -
lo1       - 172.17.2.8/32 172.17.2.8              31     -     -        0     -     -
lo1       - 172.17.2.9/32 172.17.2.9              17     -     -        0     -     -
pflog 33160 <Link#4>      pflog0                   0     0     0      506     0     0
```

`Ipkts` are packets *in* and Opackets are packets *out*. I believe that was what you are looking for.

If you want it in bytes rather than packets then add `-b` and `-d` if you are interested in dropped packets.

You can get a nice overview based on protocols using `netstat -s`

When looking at `systat` the numbers for *Traffic* and *Peak* is only for the duration of time while it is running. You can do the same basic thing using `netstat` with the `-w` wait parameter:

```
netstat -w 5 -q 2 -b -d
```

So you can find what you are looking for in the base system and have it mailed to you.

## What you are not asking

But from what you are asking I would like to point you in the direction of [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). If you want to keep an eye on network usage this is the kind of tool which is most commonly used. Others are available (ie. [netdata](https://my-netdata.io/)) and Munin itself is available as a [package](https://www.freshports.org/search.php?query=munin) on FreeBSD. And when using FreeBSD you could consider using [Mini Munin](https://erdgeist.org/arts/software/minimunin/).

It is an easy setup and will give you nice graphs like this in no time:

[image: Munin graph of network interface]